# Where can i download Grails 1.3.7?

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails, but I have an old project with me. I have to modify that project and upload it back to server. To modify that project I need Grails 1.3.7. Searched on google but couldn't find a place to download it. Please help me to find it or suggest me any other way to run my old web site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download it from official site: https://grails.org/download (select from *Download previous release*)

Or you could use GVM: http://gvmtool.net/ using

```
gvm install grails 1.3.7
```

or

```
gvm i grails 1.3.7
```

Comment: Igor Artamonov Thank a lot, thats my fault didn't see "previous release"

Answer (score 2):

[Direct download for Grails 1.3.7.](http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-1.3.7.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Mind that this is not `Grail` but `Grails`. Have a look a [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/). It hosts multiple versions, both the newest as well as older.

Comment: Opal Thank you :) fount it.